# MYSQL table creation error #1072

Tags: mysql

I ran an SQL query as follows in MYSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1_companies` (
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RSSD9001` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`),
  KEY `index1` (`RSSDID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And got the following error:

```
 #1072 - Key column 'RSSDID' doesn't exist in table `
```

Any thoughts? I am new to MYSQL.  The table does not already exist in my database.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong.

Either add `RSSDID` to the schema;

```
CREATE TABLE `table1_companies` (
  `RSSDID` INT(5) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RSSD9001` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`),
  KEY `index1` (`RSSDID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Or remove the KEY

```
CREATE TABLE `table1_companies` (
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RSSD9001` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 1):

The erroe says that all,  the column  `RSSDID` is not there in your table. You need to add that as well:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1_companies` (
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RSSDID` INT(11) NOT NULL,   --> Here
  `RSSD9001` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`),
  KEY `index1` (`RSSDID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```